# Stay div in his actual position when zoom the map

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, html5-canvas

I had done a multi-layer map, then I placed one `div` on it. But problem is that when I zoom an image that `div` should changed its position to anywhere else. For example if I placed `div` on India but when I zoom and drag it that `div` is USA or anywhere. But I want it placed in its actual position.

Here is my code:

```js
window.wheelzoom = (function() {
  var defaults = {
    zoom: 0.10
  };
  var canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
  var canvas = document.createElement('div');
  var main = function(img1, options) {
    //if (!img || !img.nodeName || img.nodeName !== 'IMG') { return; }
    var settings = {};
    var width;
    var width1;
    var height;
    var height1;
    var bgWidth;
    var bgHeight;
    var bgPosX;
    var bgPosY;
    var previousEvent;
    var cachedDataUrl;
    //console.log(img1.childNodes);
    var img = img1.childNodes[1];
    img1 = img1.childNodes[3]

    function setSrcToBackground(img, id) {
      img.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + img.src + '")';
      //$("#"+id).append("<h1 style='z-index:1;'>BHumoiraj</h1>")
      canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
      canvas.id = "raj";
      canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
      cachedDataUrl = canvas1.toDataURL();
      img.src = cachedDataUrl;
    }

    function updateBgStyle() {
      if (bgPosX > 0) {
        bgPosX = 0;
      } else if (bgPosX < width - bgWidth) {
        bgPosX = width - bgWidth;
      }
      if (bgPosY > 0) {
        bgPosY = 0;
      } else if (bgPosY < height - bgHeight) {
        bgPosY = height - bgHeight;
      }
      img.style.backgroundSize = bgWidth + 'px ' + bgHeight + 'px';
      var bd = Math.abs(bgPosY);
      var cd = Math.abs(bgPosX);

      if (bgWidth < 1281) {
        img.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://blogs-images.forbes.com/trevornace/files/2016/02/political-map-world-1200x813.jpg")';
        canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
        canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
      }
      if (bgWidth > 1281 && bgWidth < 2283) {
        img.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://www.vector-eps.com/wp-content/gallery/administrative-europe-map-vector-and-images/administrative-europe-map-image2.jpg")';
        img.style.border = "2px solid red";
      }
      if (bgWidth > 2283) {
        img.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://laraveldaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/World-Map-Blue.jpg")';
        //img.style.backgroundSize = 2000+'px '+bgHeight+'px';
      }
      img.style.backgroundPosition = bgPosX + 'px ' + bgPosY + 'px';
      //   img1.style.top = bgPosY;//"-90px" ;
      //  img1.style.left = bgPosX;//"120px";
    }

    function reset() {
      bgWidth = width;
      bgHeight = height;
      img1.style.top = height1 //"-90px" ;
      img1.style.left = width1; //"120px"; 
      bgPosX = bgPosY = 0;
      updateBgStyle();
    }

    function onwheel(e) {
      var deltaY = 0;
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.deltaY) { // FireFox 17+ (IE9+, Chrome 31+?)
        deltaY = e.deltaY;
      } else if (e.wheelDelta) {
        deltaY = -e.wheelDelta;
      }
      var rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      var offsetX = e.pageX - rect.left - window.pageXOffset;
      var offsetY = e.pageY - rect.top - window.pageYOffset;
      var bgCursorX = offsetX - bgPosX;
      var bgCursorY = offsetY - bgPosY;
      var bgRatioX = bgCursorX / bgWidth;
      var bgRatioY = bgCursorY / bgHeight;
      if (deltaY < 0) {
        bgWidth += bgWidth * settings.zoom;
        bgHeight += bgHeight * settings.zoom;
      } else {
        bgWidth -= bgWidth * settings.zoom;
        bgHeight -= bgHeight * settings.zoom;
      }
      // Take the percent offset and apply it to the new size:
      bgPosX = offsetX - (bgWidth * bgRatioX);
      bgPosY = offsetY - (bgHeight * bgRatioY);
      // Prevent zooming out beyond the starting size
      if (bgWidth <= width || bgHeight <= height) {
        reset();
      } else {
        updateBgStyle();
      }
    }

    function set(a, b, e) {
      console.log("top=" + a + "left=" + b);
      img1.style.top = b + "px"; //"-90px" ;
      img1.style.left = a + "px"; //"120px";
    }

    function drag(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      bgPosX += (e.pageX - previousEvent.pageX);
      bgPosY += (e.pageY - previousEvent.pageY);
      bgPosX += (e.pageX - previousEvent.pageX);

      set(bgPosX, bgPosY, e);
      previousEvent = e;
      updateBgStyle();
    }

    function removeDrag() {
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', removeDrag);
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag);
      }
      // Make the background draggable

    function draggable(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      previousEvent = e;
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', removeDrag);
    }

    function load() {
      if (img.src === cachedDataUrl)
        return;
      var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(img, null);
      var computedStyle1 = window.getComputedStyle(img1, null);
      width = parseInt(computedStyle.width, 10);
      height = parseInt(computedStyle.height, 10);
      width1 = parseInt(computedStyle1.top, 10);

      height1 = parseInt(computedStyle1.top, 10);
      bgWidth = width;
      bgHeight = height;
      bgPosX = 0;
      bgPosY = 0;
      setSrcToBackground(img);
      img.style.backgroundSize = width + 'px ' + height + 'px';
      img.style.backgroundPosition = '0 0';
      img.addEventListener('wheelzoom.reset', reset);
      img.addEventListener('wheel', onwheel);
      img.addEventListener('mousedown', draggable);
      img1.addEventListener('wheelzoom.reset', reset);
      img1.addEventListener('wheel', onwheel);
      img1.addEventListener('mousedown', draggable);
    }
    var destroy = function(originalProperties) {
      img.removeEventListener('wheelzoom.destroy', destroy);
      img.removeEventListener('wheelzoom.reset', reset);
      img.removeEventListener('load', load);
      img.removeEventListener('mouseup', removeDrag);
      img.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag);
      img.removeEventListener('mousedown', draggable);
      img.removeEventListener('wheel', onwheel);
      img1.removeEventListener('wheelzoom.destroy', destroy);
      img1.removeEventListener('wheelzoom.reset', reset);
      img1.removeEventListener('load', load);
      img1.removeEventListener('mouseup', removeDrag);
      img1.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag);
      img1.removeEventListener('mousedown', draggable);
      img1.removeEventListener('wheel', onwheel);
      img.style.backgroundImage = originalProperties.backgroundImage;
      img.style.backgroundRepeat = originalProperties.backgroundRepeat;
      //img.src = originalProperties.src;
    }.bind(null, {
      backgroundImage: img.style.backgroundImage,
      backgroundRepeat: img.style.backgroundRepeat
        //src: img.src
    });
    img.addEventListener('wheelzoom.destroy', destroy);
    options = options || {};
    Object.keys(defaults).forEach(function(key) {
      settings[key] = options[key] !== undefined ? options[key] : defaults[key];
    });
    if (img.complete) {
      load();
    }
    img.addEventListener('load', load);
  };
  // Do nothing in IE8
  if (typeof window.getComputedStyle !== 'function') {
    return function(elements) {
      return elements;
    };
  } else {
    return function(elements, options) {
      if (elements && elements.length) {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, main, options);
      } else if (elements && elements.nodeName) {
        main(elements, options);
      }
      return elements;
    };
  }
}());
wheelzoom(document.querySelector('div.zoom', "id"));
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='zoom' style="width: 760px;height:520px;border: 1px solid red;overflow:hidden;" id="target">
    <img class='zoom1' id="img" src='http://blogs-images.forbes.com/trevornace/files/2016/02/political-map-world-1200x813.jpg' alt='Daisy!' width='755px' height='520px' />
    <div style="position: relative;border: 1px solid red; width: 200px; height: 100px;top:-190px;">

      <img src='camera.png' alt='Daisy!' width='55px' height='20px' />
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use width and height.you can use bootstrap with col-md-... class.use divs with this kind of classes.Its helpfull to responsive.